# DBeaver adds single character when auto-completing a table name (for MariaDB databases at least)

Tags: sql, mariadb, dbeaver

DBeaver adds a character (the first letter of the table name) when auto completing table names, resulting in a query that looks like this:

```
select * from countries c;
```

As far as ***i*** can tell, it works, and has no impact on the query/results... can anyone enlighten me as to what ***it*** (the c) is?

Comment: Commonly referred to as _table alias_. Simplifies usage of qualified columns. E.g. `c.continent` instead of `countries.continent`.

Comment: ANSI/ISO SQL term is _correlation name_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"**C**" is an alias name of the "**countries**" table. Here is the reference: https://www.techonthenet.com/mariadb/alias.php